# how we can pass data on selected itemView in recylerView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I wanted to pass the selected ItemView text (which is class view here)to the next Activity so I can save other files using that name how can I do it I tried using intent but it always gives me a null exception.
Here is my recycler adapter I added a set on click listener on item view but I want to pass the name using the put extras

```
public class ClassRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ClassPost> class_list;
    public Context context;



    public ClassRecyclerAdapter(List<ClassPost> class_list){

        this.class_list = class_list;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class_list_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String class_name_data = class_list.get(position).getClass_name();
        holder.setClassText(class_name_data);



        String class_session_data = class_list.get(position).getClass_session();
        holder.setClassSession(class_session_data);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return class_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public View view;

        public TextView classView , sessionView;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view = itemView;


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Welcome to the Class"  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent newintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ClassActivity.class);

                    view.getContext().startActivity(newintent);


                }
            });





        }

        public void setClassText(String class_text){

            classView = view.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
            classView.setText(class_text);


        }

        public  void setClassSession (String class_session_text){

            sessionView = view.findViewById(R.id.class_session);
            sessionView.setText(class_session_text);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pls post your trace but I don't think you're getting null pointer when you "click", I think it's either `setClassText` or `setClassSession` that crashing - because you are not initializing these views (`classView`, `sessionView`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on but try this :

```
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public View view;

    public TextView classView , sessionView;


    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        view = itemView;
        classView = view.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        sessionView = view.findViewById(R.id.class_session);
 }
```

And for you onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {



    final String class_name_data = class_list.get(position).getClass_name();
    ((ViewHolder) holder).classView.setText(class_name_data);



    String class_session_data = class_list.get(position).getClass_session();
    ((ViewHolder) holder).sessionView.setText(class_session_data);

//Listener for the holder
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

     Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to the Class"  , 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent newintent = new Intent(context, 
          ClassActivity.class);

     context.startActivity(newintent);

        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if this work but it should